# Why is the domain name in the "Message-ID" header of an email is replaced by "@LocalDomain" in "References" header in Lotus Notes

Tags: email, jakarta-mail, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, email-headers

I am using JavaMail API to read emails from Lotus Notes.
I understand that a `Message-ID` header is a unique id for each mail and that the `References` header contains the Message-IDs of the mails that this mail is a reply to.
While reading the email header I noticed that the domain part of the email header "Message-ID" was replaced with "@LocalDomain" in the "References" email header.

For instance -

```
From : myself@abc.in  
To   : someOne@abc.in  
Message-ID : < UniqueID1@abc.in >
```

And there is a reply from someOne@abc.in , and the email header is as follows :

```
From : someOne@abc.in
To   : myself@abc.in  
Message-ID : < UniqueID2@abc.in >  
References : < UniqueID1@LocalDomain >
```

I am not quite familiar with the email headers, so I want to find out what is causing this. And if this is associated only with Lotus Notes.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Lotus Notes.  Note that there's no requirement or guarantee that the Message-ID header contains a domain name, although it's recommended.  Still, the value shouldn't be changed when included in the References header.

Comment: Notes does sometimes use @LocalDomain when it generates a new message ID, but it shouldn't ever change an existing message ID when it writes the References or In-Reply-To headers.  I cannot reproduce the problem you describe.  Please provide more details.  For example, are both myself@abc.in and someOne@abc.in using Notes? Do you see this behavior for every reply from all users?  Also, do you know if the messages are in native Notes or MIME format?

Comment: @DaveDelay Yes, both From and To are using Notes. And also, this behavior is seen for every reply from a Notes user.
I do not know in what format the messages are, can you tell how I can check that?

Comment: To check if a message is in MIME format:  1) Select the message in Notes, 2) Press Alt-Enter, 3) Select the second tab (triangle icon), 4) Look for an item named $NoteHasNativeMIME.  If the item value is "1" it's a MIME message.  If the item is missing, it's in native Notes format.  Also what version of Notes is this?

Answer (score 0):

As I said in a comment, "Notes does sometimes use @LocalDomain when it generates a new message ID, but it [should never] change an existing message ID when it writes the References or In-Reply-To headers. I cannot reproduce the problem you describe."

In other words, it looks like a defect (in Notes or the JavaMail API or ?).  If it's a Notes defect, StackOverflow is not the right place to resolve it.